# Creating tables in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame and I want to create a specific table in R showing the summary statistics. Getting the summary statistics aren't a problem, it is just formatting the table.

Here is my data

```
df1 <- data.frame(DAY = c(0,1,0,1), Value = c(1,2,3,4),Change=c(0,4,8,10),treatment=rep("A",4))
df2  <- data.frame(DAY = c(0,1,0,1), Value = c(5,6,7,8),Change=c(5,7,8,9),treatment=rep("B",4))

data <- rbind(df1,df2)
```

I want the table to look like

```
                  Drug A                     Drug B         
                  (N = 2)                    (N = 2)                  
    ___________________________  _______________________________

  _________Value______Change___________Value _____ Change                                       
DAY 0                                                                                                                             
n               2           2             2          2                     
Mean            2           4             6          6.5                       

Day 1                                                                                                                                         
n               2           2             2          2
Mean            3           7             7          8
```

I don't care about the lines, they are just there to make the table easier to understand

I tried formatting the data frame by having a matrix with the column names of Value, change, value and change and the row names being day 0, n, mean, day 1, n and mean with the day rows being an empty string but I'm missing the Drug A and drug B parts.

Comment: are you looking for this to be the printed format in the R console?  Or output to some other document type?

Comment: You may want to look at  `?ftable()`

Comment: Printed format in the R console preferably.

Comment: A better bet might be the `tables` package; though principally designed for LaTeX export, it will allow some multi-level tables like this.  See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/vignettes/tables.pdf for some examples.